# Match the Level of Variables from Two Dataset

Tags: r

I am working on a forecasting model and need to match the levels of each variable from training data and testing data using the code shown as below:

```
levels(test$MSSubClass) <- levels(train$MSSubClass)
```

There are 87 variables in total. Instead of doing it one by one. I am looking for an approach to match them all at one time. Currently, my code is like this:

```
levels(test$MSSubClass) <- levels(train$MSSubClass)
levels(test$MSZoning) <- levels(train$MSZoning)
levels(test$LotFrontage) <- levels(train$LotFrontage)
levels(test$LotArea) <- levels(train$LotArea)
levels(test$Street) <- levels(train$Street)
....
```

Comment: FACT = which(sapply(train, class) == "factor");   
for(i in FACT) { levels(test[,i]) <- levels(train[,i]) }

Answer (score 0):

If the levels in `test` are a subset of the levels in `train`:

```
# Get the column names that are factors
factor_names <- names(train)[sapply(train, class) == "factor"]

# Set the factor levels in test to be same as train
for (name in factor_names) {levels(test[,name]) <- levels(train[,name])}
```